# Which languages are involved in the configuration of TYPO3?

Tags: configuration, typo3

Which languages are involved in the configuration of TYPO3 with default extensions?

Comment: You've posted quite a lot of unanswered questions, maybe it would be better to slow down, do some more independent research and wait for answers before building on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **TypoScript** Used for frontend configuration

   - [TyposcriptReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/)
2. **Symfony ExpressionLanguage** Used for conditions in TypoScript (TYPO3 9+)

   - [Symfony ExpressionLanguage](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference.html)
3. **Regular Expression** Used in TypoScript

   - [Replacement](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Functions/Replacement.html?highlight=RegExp#useregexp)
   - [config.linkVars](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=regex#linkvars)
   - ...
4. **TSConfig** Used for backend configuration

   - [TSconfigReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/)
5. **YAML** Used for sites configuration (TYPO3 9+)

   - [Site Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html)
6. **PHP** Used for extensions, local configuration, TCA, ...

   - [Extension Configuration Files](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html)
   - [Local Configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/8.7/CoreArchitecture/Configuration/LocalConfiguration/Index.html)
   - [TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/)
   - ...
7. **XML** Used for FlexForms configuration

   - [FlexForms](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Flex.html#columns-flex)
8. **Environment Variables** Used to define Application Context (TYPO3_CONTEXT)

   - [Application Context](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Bootstrapping/Index.html#application-context)
9. **JSON** For composer.json configuration (Only in case you use composer installation)

   - [Install TYPO3 via composer](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html)
10. **SQL** Used in ext_tables.sql to change existing tables or create new tables in database

    - [ext_tables.sql](https://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Developers_Guide#ext_tables.sql_.28optional.29)
    - [Preparing the database](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/1-prepare-the-database.html#preparing-the-tables-of-the-domain-objects)

**Translations**

1. **XML** (XLIFF) Used for translation

   - [XLIFF](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/Internationalization/Translation/)

**Templating**

1. **FLUID** Used as template enging

   - [FLUID](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/Index.html)
2. **TypoScript** Used for frontend templating

   - [TyposcriptReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/)

**Webserver**

1. **Apache Configuration** (Apache Webserver only)

   - mod_rewrite in .htaccess/.conf used for human readable urls
   - php settings in .htaccess
2. **Nginx Configuration** (Nginx Webserver only)

   - Used for human readable urls
3. **INI**

   - php.ini to define php settings

Maybe i am missing some points, please report in comments :)

Comment: Also think of XML for language files.

Comment: I added XML for FlexForm configuration. Thanks for your suggestion. I am not sure if language files are part of configuration? Hmmm :)

Comment: If YAML is configuration, XML is too. I am not quite sure with Fluid. It's a template language and TypoScript is also one.

Comment: Ok i added 2 new headlines Translation/Templating for XML and Fluid.

Comment: Good solution. That are the corner cases. I am curious, if we detect some more.

Comment: Detected one more and added Environment Variables.

Comment: Added Webserver. I am not sure if this is really related to TYPO3, its related to all kind of web application. So i created a new headline for this.
Added JSON in case of composer installation

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85829 https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Comment: Updated and added Symfony ExpressionLanguage

Comment: Added SQL for ext_tables.sql

Comment: Are there regex in TypoScript?

Comment: Looks like there are RegEx in some cases:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Functions/Replacement.html?highlight=RegExp#useregexp

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=regex#linkvars

Is RegEx a "language" ? Or just a syntax ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression It's a language and a classical subject of language theory.

Comment: Added Regular Expression. :)

Comment: Started with three, ended with ten. If you ever need to write a CV, it's half done.